# Swift - instantiate class from type returned in a function

Tags: swift

Is it possible to return the type of a class from a function?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
func giveMeAClass() -> AnyClass {
    return String.self
}

let theClass = giveMeAClass()

let instantiatedFromTheClass = theClass()

let castedFromTheClass = someObject as! theClass
```

EDIT:

Another example where I'm trying to do something more useful

```
class BaseModel {
    var baseProperty: String!
}

class TextModel: BaseModel {
    var textProperty: String!
}

class DateModel: BaseModel {
    var dateProperty: NSDate!
}

class BaseCell<T: BaseModel>: UITableViewCell {
    var model: T!
}

class TextCell: BaseCell<TextModel> {

}

class DateCell: BaseCell<DateModel> {

}

func getCellTypeForModel(model: BaseModel) -> ??? {

    if model is TextModel {
        return TextCell.Type // ???
    }

    else if model is DateModel {
        return DateCell.self // ???
    }

    return BaseCell.somethingElse // ???
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let model = cellModels[indexPath.item] as! BaseModel
    let cellType = getCellTypeForModel(anyModel)
    let castedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellType

    // give the model to the cell, customize it, etc

    return castedCell
}
```

Comment: `String` is not a class. It is a value-type.

Answer (score 2):

When initializing from metatypes, you need to explicitly call the `initializer`. E.g.

```
protocol SimplyInitializable { init() }

extension String: SimplyInitializable {}
extension Int: SimplyInitializable {}

class Foo : SimplyInitializable {
    let foo : Int
    required init() { foo = 42 }
}

func getType<T: SimplyInitializable>(type: T.Type) -> SimplyInitializable.Type {
    return type
}

/* example usage */
var MyType = getType(String)
let foo = MyType.init() as! String // "", String

MyType = getType(Int)
let bar = MyType.init() as! Int // 0, Int

MyType = getType(Foo)
let baz = MyType.init() as! Foo
baz.foo // 42
```

Note that you needn't a function to make the metatype assignment, e.g.

```
let MyType2 : SimplyInitializable.Type = Foo.self
let foobar = MyType2.init()
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I'm looking for, I'll edit my answer to show a more complete use case. You don't need that protocol by the way. You can just do this: https://gist.github.com/johanhar/33823c396e8bfa697fb5

Comment: @Johannes Happy to help. Note that the protocol does in fact have a subtle use in the example above. In you gist link we have no layer of abstraction, and the `getType(..)` function is entirely equivalent to setting the metatype directly `let MyType = Foo.self`. In that case, `MyType` has value `Foo.Type`, and knowing this _specific non-generic knowledge about `Foo`_, we can call the initializer `init()`. In my protocol example above, we have a layer of abstraction using `SimplyInitializable.Type` as metatype, knowing that all types conforming to `Simpl..` will have an `init()` initializer.

Comment: You have a point, good explanation. I edited my answer with an example that is closer to what I'm actually trying to do